# I can't use session in nodejs. how can i make safe listing?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next-auth

In my project that I created using nextjs, I want the session to list while I make a listing query on the backend. If there is no session, I want it not to give authorized permission. I am using next authentication. I can't pull next in session But I can't get session. Can you help me, please?

```
Offers.belongsTo(Users, {as: 'User', foreignKey: 'user_id'});
router.post('/api/logistic/offers/get-offers', async (req, res) => {
    const {limit, page, sortColumn, sortType, search, session} = req.body;
    if(session){

        const total = await Offers.findAll();
        const offersList = await Offers.findAll({
            limit: limit,
            offset: (page - 1) * limit,
            order: [
                [sortColumn, sortType]
            ],
            where: {
                [Op.or]: [
                    {
                        offers_no: {
                            [Op.substring]: [
                                search
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        agreement_date: {
                            [Op.substring]: [
                                search
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        routes: {
                            [Op.substring]: [
                                search
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        type_of_the_transport: {
                            [Op.substring]: [
                                search
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                ]
            },
            include: [{
                model: Users,
                as: 'User'

            }]
        });
        res.json({
            total: total.length,
            data: offersList
        });
    }else {
        res.status(401).send(JSON.stringify({
            status: "error",
            title: 'Unauthorized',
            message: 'Unauthorized'
        }));
    }

})
```

The error I get in the terminal is always like this. I can't use session

[image]

```
//offers list
Offers.belongsTo(Users, {as: 'User', foreignKey: 'user_id'});
router.post('/api/logistic/offers/get-offers', async (req, res) => {
    const session = await getSession({req});
    console.log(session);
    if(session){
        const {limit, page, sortColumn, sortType, search} = req.body;
        const total = await Offers.findAll();
        const offersList = await Offers.findAll({
            limit: limit,
            offset: (page - 1) * limit,
            order: [
                [sortColumn, sortType]
            ],
            where: {
                [Op.or]: [
                    {
                        offers_no: {
                            [Op.substring]: [
                                search
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        agreement_date: {
                            [Op.substring]: [
                                search
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        routes: {
                            [Op.substring]: [
                                search
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        type_of_the_transport: {
                            [Op.substring]: [
                                search
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                ]
            },
            include: [{
                model: Users,
                as: 'User'

            }]
        });
        res.json({
            total: total.length,
            data: offersList
        });
    }else {
        res.status(401).send(JSON.stringify({
            status: "error",
            title: 'Unauthorized',
            message: 'Unauthorized'
        }));
    }

})
```

This is how my code was before. but it didn't work.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't mention. but I am using next authentication. I can't pull next in session